# Why does ThreadPoolTaskScheduler launch task several times concurrently?

Tags: java, spring

I developed a mqtt application with spring and Netty. There is `MqttPingScheduleHandler` sends ping requests periodically. It has an `@PostConstruct` method that launches a runnable task (inner class) by `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.
If a ping response is not received in a few seconds (20sec), a `PingTimeoutEvent` is published. This is how it happens for the first time.

```
2021-09-21 18:58:41.861 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run
FINE: Sent ping request. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@14b83570. Message MqttMessage[fixedHeader=MqttFixedHeader[messageType=PINGREQ, isDup=false, qosLevel=AT_MOST_ONCE, isRetain=false, remainingLength=0], variableHeader=, payload=].
2021-09-21 18:59:01.873 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run
WARNING: Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@14b83570
2021-09-21 18:59:01.875 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler publishPingTimeoutEvent
WARNING: Publish PingTimeoutEvent. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler@13b5ae8
2021-09-21 18:59:01.876 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttClientImpl reconnect
INFO: Start reconnect! Attempt 1.
```

Everything breaks down in the second time when a ping response is not received again. Multiple events are published with minimal (1-3 ms) time difference. The number of concurrent launches can reach 10 or more.

```
2021-09-21 19:01:28.778 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run
FINE: Sent ping request. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@6f6c557a. Message MqttMessage[fixedHeader=MqttFixedHeader[messageType=PINGREQ, isDup=false, qosLevel=AT_MOST_ONCE, isRetain=false, remainingLength=0], variableHeader=, payload=].
2021-09-21 19:01:28.779 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run <-- It should be run in 20 seconds!
WARNING: Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@6f6c557a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.779 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler publishPingTimeoutEvent
WARNING: Publish PingTimeoutEvent. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler@4dbee29a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.779 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run <-- It should be run in 40 seconds!
WARNING: Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@6f6c557a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.779 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler publishPingTimeoutEvent
WARNING: Publish PingTimeoutEvent. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler@4dbee29a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.780 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask run <-- It should be run in 60 seconds and so on!
WARNING: Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler$RunnableTask@6f6c557a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.780 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler publishPingTimeoutEvent
WARNING: Publish PingTimeoutEvent. ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttPingScheduleHandler@4dbee29a
2021-09-21 19:01:28.782 ru.maxeltr.mqttClient.Mqtt.MqttClientImpl reconnect
INFO: Start reconnect! Attempt 2.
```

I can't understand what's going on. I think `run()` method is multiple launched by `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. Why `run()` method runs several times at once?

```
/*
 * For scheduling a ping request with a fixed delay which is defined by config (MqttPingScheduleHandler)
 */
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}

/*
 * For scheduling a ping request with a fixed delay which is defined by config (MqttPingScheduleHandler)
 */
@Bean
public PeriodicTrigger pingPeriodicTrigger(Config config) {
    String keepAliveTimer = config.getProperty("keepAliveTimer", "20");
    if (keepAliveTimer.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid keepAliveTimer property");
    }
    PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(Long.parseLong(keepAliveTimer, 10), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true);
    periodicTrigger.setInitialDelay(Long.parseLong(keepAliveTimer, 10));
    return periodicTrigger;
}
```

```java
  

  public class MqttPingScheduleHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MqttPingHandler.class.getName());
        private final Config config;
        private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
        private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;
        private PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger;
        private boolean pingRequestWasSent;
        private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;
        private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
        
        public MqttPingScheduleHandler(Config config, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler, PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
            this.config = config;
            this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
            this.periodicTrigger = periodicTrigger;
            this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
            logger.log(Level.FINE, String.format("Create ping handler: %s", this));
            System.out.println(String.format("Create ping handler: %s", this));
        }
        
        @PostConstruct
        public void scheduleRunnableWithCronTrigger() {
            this.future = taskScheduler.schedule(new RunnableTask(), periodicTrigger);
        }
        
        private void publishPingTimeoutEvent() {
            applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new PingTimeoutEvent(this, "Ping response was not received for keepAlive time."));
            System.out.println(String.format("Publish PingTimeoutEvent. %s", this));
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("Publish PingTimeoutEvent. %s", this));
        }
        
        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ...
            switch (message.fixedHeader().messageType()) {
                case PINGRESP:
                    logger.log(Level.FINE, String.format("Received ping response %s.", msg));
                    System.out.println(String.format("Received ping response %s.", msg));
                    this.pingRequestWasSent = false;
                    break;
            ...
        }
    
        class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
            public RunnableTask() {
                System.out.println(String.format("Create sending ping task in ping handler. %s", this));
                logger.log(Level.FINE, String.format("Create sending ping task in ping handler. %s.", this));
            }
    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (pingRequestWasSent) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. %s", this));
                    logger.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("Ping response was not received for keepAlive time. %s", this));
                    publishPingTimeoutEvent();
                    return;
                }
    
                MqttFixedHeader fixedHeader = new MqttFixedHeader(MqttMessageType.PINGREQ, false, MqttQoS.AT_MOST_ONCE, false, 0);
                MqttMessage msg = new MqttMessage(fixedHeader);
                ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
                pingRequestWasSent = true;
                logger.log(Level.FINE, String.format("Sent ping request. %s. Message %s.", this, msg));
                System.out.println(String.format("Sent ping request. %s. Message %s.", this, msg));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be `periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true)`. Fixed rate means that scheduled task will be triggered no matter if previous task had been completed; time is measured from the ***beginning*** of previous execution. Fixed delay, on the other hand, means that next execution will happen after previous execution completes; time is measured from the ***end*** of previous execution. See `PeriodicTrigger#nextExecutionTime`

Comment: You are right.  run() method is multiple launched because of executions accumulate in queue.